# delete/move/yank multiple sections vim

Tags: vim, editor, yank

I'm aware that you can delete say lines 34-40 with
`:34,40d` but is there a way to delete say lines 34-40 AND lines 43-45

something like
`:34,40(?)43,45d` where (?) represents the symbol necessary to tell vim AND this second set of rows?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, there's [vim.se] for these questions that might get you a better answer.

Comment: [There's this nonsense](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/specifying-multiple-ranges-in-vim-td5151682.html) but it appears to be far easier to just to do 2 separate commands

Comment: Not by default, I think there are scripts,  you can  do  :43,45d|34,40d  which will delete, but if you also want to capture it in a reg, this will only have the last delete.  You have to specify it backwards otherwise you can get surprising results

Comment: the | suggestion wont work as intended because the second range will be altered by the first operation

Answer (score 2):

There's no usable built-in way to do exactly what you want.

But this is simple enough IMO:

```
:34,40d|43-45d
```

There's another way to look at it. If those lines share a `pattern`, you could do:

```
:g/pattern/d
```

Comment: that actually wont work as intended because the second range will be altered by the first operation

Comment: It will work though if you delete farther lines first, then nearer.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is just duplicating the `:d[elete]` command and concatenating all commands in one command-line. For mutable commands (like `:delete`), you need to start from the end, so that the line numbers are still valid:

```
:43,45d|34,40d
```

#### With plugin

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides (among many others) a `:RangeDo` command that simplifies the handling, as it adapts the ranges for mutations and ensures that each line is processed only once:

```
:RangeDo 34,40 43,45 d
```

#### Yanks

With or without plugin, each single range still results in a separate command invocation. To accumulate yanks in a single register, you have to use the *uppercase* version that appends (on all but the first invocation):

```
:34,40yank a | 43,45yank A
:let @a = '' | RangeDo 34,40 43,45 yank A
```